# how to get columncount in gridview

Tags: android, gridview

How to get column count in Gridview when **gridview noofColumn="autofit"** mode

**How to get single row no of column**

```
<GridView
                android:id="@+id/gridview"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"

                android:background="@android:color/white"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:numColumns="auto_fit"
                android:stretchMode="columnWidth" />
```

Comment: in grid view "autofit" mode, will consider 2 columns in a portarate mode, 3 columns in landscape mode.

Answer (score 7):

You can get column count in java code..

```
GridView mGridView = (GridView)findViewById(R.id.gridview);
int column_coutnt = mGridView.getNumColumns();
```

**Second Way:**

```
int columns = 0;
int children = mGridView.getChildCount();
if (children > 0) {
     int width = mGridView.getChildAt(0).getMeasuredWidth();
     if (width > 0) {
        columns = mGridView.getWidth() / width;
     }
 }
```

Comment: @Sanket990 [check this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12231835/how-to-get-the-number-of-rows-of-a-gridview) and [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7874011/624069)

Answer (score 1):

Try like this..

```
Math.ceil( (double)gridView.getCount() / (double)gridView.getNumColumns() );
```